# Cycle through range in Sheets, and return an item from said list every week?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to make a simple list of everyone working in my office, and then have someone listed as this weeks "maid", or "bringer-of-friday-cake" in that same sheet, automatically cycling through that list every monday, assigning a different person, until the list eventually starts over in the same pattern. The assigning part could simple, like conditional formatting, or maybe just an "X" in the cell next to the person.

Something like this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d03P7.png)

I'll admit I cant even begin to think how I would do this, so I can't say I have tried anything yet. Don't even know what a function like that would be called, in order to search for it online. So I'm hoping one of you have some wisdom :) I have a feeling it's reeeeeally easy, but I don't know where to begin :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this to count the number of weeks from a start date, compare it with the current row and return to the beginning if(in this case) 5 weeks or more have passed:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(B4:B="","",if(mod(quotient(D3-C3,7),counta(B4:B))=row(B4:B)-row(B4),"X","")))
```

In practice you would replace D3 by Today(), but you can't test it that way without waiting till a few weeks have elapsed.

*Week 1*

[image]

*Week 2*

[image]

*Week 5*

[image]

Comment: Sounds good :) But how does the code know when the list of people is done, and needs to start over? Is that the "Counta" function?

Comment: Yes - the Quotient part works out how many complete weeks have passed, then Mod together with Counta works out how far down the list it is, compares it with the current row minus the start row, and goes back to the beginning if you run off the end.